# Django Dynamically serving static files.(Chunk Load error )

Tags: django, reactjs

I have a Django + React project running at localHost:8000.

VIEWS.PY

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'frontend/index.html')
```

INDEX.HTML

```
{% load static %}
<script src="{% static "frontend/main.js" %}"></script>
```

When user click a button in `main.js` file, it request for `0.bundle.js` to server, but server fails to serve it.

I can't do loading manually  (`<script src="{% static "frontend/0.main.js" %}"></script>` This scripts load the `0.bundle.js` but I want dynamic import).

As you can see in attached image, the frontend JS file requesting file at rootLocalhost.[image]

Any ideas or directions will be appreciated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

configured webpack as below,new chunk files will point to Django static files

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
          "style-loader",
          // Translates CSS into CommonJS
          "css-loader",
          // Compiles Sass to CSS
          "sass-loader",
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  output: {
    chunkFilename: "static/frontend/[name].bundle.js",
  },
};
```

Comment: move bundle file to static files then